# Separating variables

Tags: sas

I have below data in visit variable

```
Screening DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
CycleXX DayXX
Endofthetreatment DayXX
```

We have Cycles and days in the visit, now Sponsor asking populate only Cycle in the Visit variable without Screening and End of the study

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you might find the `scan` function useful for this, and you could use `where` or `if` to stop the `Screening` and `Endofthetreatment` lines coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where` statement to only keep lines where the word "Cycle" is in it. You can then use the `input`, `compress`, and `scan` functions to select a specific string, keep only digits, and convert it to a number.

```
data have;
    infile datalines dlm='|';
    length visit $30.;
    input visit$;
    datalines;
Screening Day01
Cycle01 Day02
Cycle01 Day03
Cycle01 Day04
Cycle02 Day04
Cycle02 Day06
Cycle02 Day07
Cycle03 Day08
Cycle03 Day09
Endofthetreatment Day10
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    where upcase(visit) contains 'CYCLE';

    /* Keep only digits from the first and second words and
       convert it to a number */
    cycle = input(compress(scan(visit, 1),, 'DK'), 2.);
    day   = input(compress(scan(visit, 2),, 'DK'), 2.);

    drop visit;
run;
```

Output:

```
cycle   day
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       4
2       6
2       7
3       8
3       9
```